# Sets a dot after numbering in the table of contents after a custom section style

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, formatting, numbering, section-titles

Good afternoon everyone, can anyone help with the following problem?

I have a task to have a list in the table of contents with numbers in the list and titles, with only numbers in the text. Accordingly, the text of the section should go after the number without going to the next line.

To solve this problem, I use the definition of the new command

```
\makeatletter    
\renewcommand\subsection{%
    \@startsection{subsection}{1}{\z@}%
    {3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
    {\centering\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\makeatother}
```

In this case the dot at the end of the number before the name of the section is missing in the Table of Contents itself.

The full code listing is given below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{concrete, eulervm}


\usepackage[a4paper, total={170mm, 257mm},
            left=2cm, right=1cm,
            top=1cm, bottom=1.5cm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\patchcmd{\appendices}{\quad}{. }{}{}


\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{misccorr}
\usepackage{indentfirst}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.0em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0.5em}{2.5em}}
\renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1em}{3.0em}}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
    \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
    \fi
    \@tempskipa #5\relax
    \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
    #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
        \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname.}%
        \fi
        #7}%
    \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
        #6{\hskip #3\relax
            \@svsec #8}%
        \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
            \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
            \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
            \fi
            #7}}%
    \fi
    \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\newcommand\runinsubsection{%
    \@startsection{subsection}%
    {2}% level
    {\z@}% indentation of heading from the left margin
    {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}% absolute value = beforeskip
    {-0.5em \@plus -.1em}% when negative, opposite = skip to leave right of a
    % run-in heading.
    {\normalfont\bfseries}% style
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\section[Section 1]{Text Section 1}

\runinsubsection[Subsection 1]{}
Text in Subsection 1.

\subsection[Subsection 2]{}
Text in Subsection 2.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want only  to modify the ToC adding a dot like `1.1. Subsection 1` ?

Comment: Yes, and, to be honest, I don’t even quite understand why the dot disappears when compiling pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a dot missing.

```
     ...
    \def\@svsechd{%
        #6{\hskip #3\relax
            \@svsec #8}%
        \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
            \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
            \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname.}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            \fi
            #7}}%
    \fi
    \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother
```

[image: a]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sssur  Qut of curiosity, why are you loading `misccorr`?

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember why I have this package in my preamble templates. Maybe I accidentally copied it from somewhere. )))

If it's no secret, what does it do and in general what is it for? :-)

Comment: @Sssur It is for using `babel` with the option `russian` But also modifies  section titles and ToC.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I think I added this package in order to use `\varepsilon` and `\varphi` in formulas.